# Create a .txt file if doesn't exist with user inputted data

Tags: c#, forms

Is there any way to create a text file using a name that comes from data entered in a form?

```
string path = @"E:\AppServ\**Example**.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
}
```

`**Example**` being the part taken from user inputted data.

Similar to this `Console.Writeline("{0}", userData);`

Comment: Look at `string.Format()`

Comment: Are you meaning to use wild characters or actual asterisks in your string? For the file creation process you can do this: `FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path); if (!file.Exists && file.Directory.Exists) { file.Create(); }else{ //Handle Failure }`

Comment: @MathiasBecher surely`Path.Combine()` would be better?

Comment: that was just to highlight what part I meant to be user data.

Comment: Path.Combine() seems to be quite a good option, ill rejig some code and see if it does what I want it to do :) thanks

Comment: @stuartd That is correct. This is better for paths. I wanted to also give the solution to the more general problem of formatting strings, as Mr. Bottell did not seem to know that.

Comment: File.AppendText is the best way. It creates the file if not exists. Use filestream only if the data is very large and comes in a stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to store files to the logged in users My Documents folder on windows.

You can modify the AppendUserFile function to support other file modes.  This version will open the file for Appending if it exists, or create it if it doesn't exist.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppendUserFile("example.txt", tw =>
            {
                tw.WriteLine("I am some new text!");
            });

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private static bool AppendUserFile(string fileName, Action<TextWriter> writer)
        {
            string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            FileStream fs = null;
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
            else
                fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
            using (fs)
            {
                try
                {
                    TextWriter tw = (TextWriter)new StreamWriter(fs);
                    writer(tw);
                    tw.Flush();
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a rather confusing example. And please don't use string.Concat to combine paths and filenames, that's what Path.Combine is for.

Comment: I updated it to Environment.SpecialFolder and Path.Combine.  It should be noted though that path.combine essentially does the same thing as string.concat except it makes sure you don't end up with extra \\'s (path deviders).

Comment: I don't know why you'd call .Dispose() manually when you can just put the whole FileStream in a using block

Comment: I wasn't sure if the writer callback crashed, if the using block would still close.  Does it?